# Can't load music into pygame

Tags: python, pygame

please help if you can. Can't seem to be able to upload music into my game in progress.
It comes up with the error of "can't load"...
Would be great if someone got back to me quick, This is a major work due in 1 week

```
import sys, random, pygame, time
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("game")
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("cambria", 19)
myfont2 = pygame.font.SysFont("cambria", 45)
myfont3 = pygame.font.SysFont("cambria", 30)

#music

pygame.mixer.music.load('sddmusic.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)



def print_text(font, x, y, text, color):
    imgText = font.render(text, True, color)
    screen.blit(imgText, (x,y))

game = False
white = 255,255,255

mouse_down_x = mouse_down_y = 0
mouse_down = 0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_down = event.button
            mouse_down_x, mouse_down_y = event.pos

    screen.fill((85,107,47))

    #print_text(myfont,0,0, str(mouse_down), white)
    #print_text(myfont,0,15, str(mouse_down_x), white)
    #print_text(myfont,0,30, str(mouse_down_y), white) 

    if game == True:
        pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (100,0), (100,600), 20)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, white, (500,0), (500,600), 20)
        time_get = time.clock() - time_start


        if time_get > 1:
           print_text(myfont, 240,0 ,"Hello?", (255,255,255))
        if time_get > 1.75:
            print_text(myfont, 240,50, "Commander?", (255,255,255))
        if time_get > 2.2:
            print_text(myfont, 240,100, "Do you copy?",(255,255,255))

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white,(204,176,200,40),2)
        print_text(myfont2, 100, 100,"Operation L.A.U.N.C.H", (255,255,255))
        print_text(myfont3,270,176, "Start", white)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white,(204,280,200,40),2)
        print_text(myfont3,270,280, "Quit", white)

        if mouse_down == 1 and mouse_down_x > 204 and mouse_down_y > 176 and mouse_down_x < 404 and mouse_down_y < 216:
            game = True
            mouse_down = 0
            mouse_down_x = 0
            mouse_down_y = 0
            time_start = time.clock()


        if mouse_down == 1 and mouse_down_x > 204 and mouse_down_y > 280 and mouse_down_x < 404 and mouse_down_y < 320:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()




    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What steps have you taken to investigate the problem?

Comment: I've researched a fair bit and looked through youtube videos. i've also tried the different file forms like mp3, wav, ogg. I think the main problem is that it doesn't recognise the mp3 file for some reason. Hope that's more clear now :)

Comment: The docs say "Be aware that MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program, e.g. Debian Linux. Consider using OGG instead."  Does wav and ogg work?

Comment: if i used wav or ogg would i have to change the music file name itself?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is due to the following reason:
1)Go go to file > save as (shortcut : Ctrl+Shift+S) and try saving the python file in the same address in which your music is stored.

Suggestion:
Try converting the mp3 to wav.It works better.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter the full path of your mp3. For example

```
    pygame.mixer.music.load('C:/Users/path/to/your/file/sddmusic.mp3')
```