# Cannot load music in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

The code I am using is this:

```
import pygame
assert pygame.init()==(6,0)
pygame.mixer.init()
from pygame.locals import *
from time import sleep
import os
pygame.mixer.music.load('timer_end.mp3')
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\Lib\timer.py", line 60, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load('timer_end.mp3')
pygame.error: Couldn't open 'timer_end.mp3'
```

I have also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638671/cant-load-music-into-pygame) and its answer. They are, unfortunately, not helpful because the `.mp3` was, to begin with, in the same file as my Python script. How can I get PyGame music to work correctly?

Comment: Can you play the media file outside of python?  And can you echo the working path and the full file path to ensure you are running where you expect?

Comment: @Matt Yes, I can play it outside of Python. As for your second question, I have ensured that both my program and the music file are in the same directory.

Comment: The same directory does not always means python can find it.  Try the full path.  The search path is based on the working directory.

Comment: @Matt If it couldn't find it, wouldn't the error be a `FileNotFoundError`?

Comment: Actually, that is the error pygame gives when the file is not found. So maybe @Matt is right. Try to use the full path, and build it with the help of the `os.path` functions, which is safer and less error prone than write the full path by hand.

Comment: @Valentino      "...when the file is not found..." ~ Valentino

"...does not always mean python can find it..." ~ Matt

Comment: I mean that when the filename is not correct (wrong path) pygame returns the error you reported in your question, not a `FileNotFoundError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### mp3 not recognized

Not sure if this is the problem, since it seems to me you are using windows, but check the [pygame music docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html). They say:

> Be aware that MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program, e.g. Debian Linux. Consider using OGG instead.

So try to convert the file to another format, like WAV or OGG. Maybe it works.

#### use full path

The error you posted is the error pygame gives when the file is not found. So maybe @Matt in his comment is right.
Try to use the full path, and build it with the help of the `os.path` functions, they are safer and less error prone than writing the full path by hand.
If you are sure that the music file is in the same directory where is the python script, you can get its full path by doing: `os.path.abspath("timer_end.mp3")`

As last resource, the following code will extrapolate the path of the python file and build the full path of the file music assuming that it is in the same directory. It should work even if you launch the python script from another directory.

```
filepath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
filedir = os.path.dirname(filepath)
musicpath = os.path.join(filedir, "timer_end.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.load(musicpath)
```

Comment: I tried this and, unfortunately, the same problem occurs.

Comment: @PalpableCoral I edit my question with another alternative

Comment: I tried your second solution, which still does not work.

Comment: You are sure that the file is in the same directory where the script is. But do you call the script from the same directory? If you add `print(os.getcwd())` to the script, it will print the directory where your script is?

Comment: I used `os.path.abspath("...")` which did not work.

Comment: @PalpableCoral I've edited again my answer. If it still does not work, please explain why and what kind of error you get now.

Comment: When I tried `os.path.abspath()` I got the same error as before and, even now (with your updated solution), I am getting the same error.

Comment: Then I am out of ideas, sorry. The error is clearly telling you that the file cannot be found, and I cannot understand why.

Comment: I am thinking that it is perhaps because it is in my C drive in my python folder, it may not have access to that. That is something I will look into fixing. No worries :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error is caused because the file is not found.  For example take the Windows sample `Kalimba.mp3`.  Here I have a python file in the `Sample Music` location that is called from another location.

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('Kalimba.mp3')
```

This results in `Couldn't open 'Kalimba.mp3'` error.  If I change to the full path

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('<full path>Kalimba.mp3')
```

This runs without an error.  I recommend that you use a music library as described in [this tutorial](https://nerdparadise.com/programming/pygame/part3) to organize your asset files.